# String questions

Tags: java, string

I have a problem and a question with using Strings.

The problem I am having is reading a line in a text file. Let's say in my .txt file I have the word 'hello' and I am simply trying to validate that the user inputs the same thing.

The .txt file simply has the word 'hello'

Here is the code.

```
String fileWord;

File filename = fileOpen.getSelectedFile(); // Open the .txt file
FileReader filereader = new FileReader(filename);
BufferedReader inputFile = new BufferedReader(filereader);

String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Say hello");
fileWord = inputFile.readLine();

if (input == fileWord)
     System.out.println("They match!");
```

However, this doesn't work. I did a System.out.println on both **input and fileWord** and they appear to be the same, but they're not as the if() statement doesn't work.

***Another question*** I have is if in a .txt file I have on **one** line 'hello goodbye' how do I read one word on a line at a time? For example, if the user inputs 'hello' then it finds it in the text file and returns 'goodbye'.

**EDIT**
I've gotten further in my program and have run into another issue. Whenever a user inputs a word, if it doesn't find the word in the file, it is suppose to write the word to a new file. In my program, I'm using a loop to search through the file to find the word. When I input a word that doesn't exist in the file, I get an exception error and the program closes. I can't quite figure out where and how I figure out that the word isn't in the file.

```
while (!input.equals(fileWord))
{
     fileWord = inputFile.readLine();
     String[] wordSplit = englishWord.split("\\s+", 2);
     fileWord = wordSplit[0];
     fileWord2 = wordSplit[1];
}

System.out.println("The opposite of " + fileWord + " is " + fileWord2);
```

This example would find "hello" in the text file and output "goodbye" and that works fine. But, if I put some random word as the input and it won't find it, what do I do to move on and proceed with adding it into a new file? I can figure out how to write to a file, I think...I just can't get out of the loop correctly without an exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `equals()` to compare strings and not `==`:

```
if (input.equals(fileWord))
```

As to your second question, the easiest way is to read the entire line, then `split()` it. That'll give you a two-element array of Strings. You can use the first element for comparison and return the second element if there's a match:

```
String[] words = line.split("\\s+", 2);
// words[0] will contain "hello"
// words[1] will contain "goodbye"
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you so much. Could you give a brief explanation on "\\s+"?

Comment: @user1015523: It is a regular expression that matches one or more consecutive whitespaces. There much too little space here to explain regular expressions. I suggest you take a look at this tutorial: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/

Comment: Is there a way to move on from the loop-method of finding the equal word if the word doesn't exist? I edited my original post to further explain.

Comment: Actually, I think I got it working using a try and catch around the while loop with (Exception e) as the catch. Is this a good way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use equals(), not == to compare two String for equality. Using == with objects returns true only if both sides refer to the exact same object (Two Strings with same contents are still two different String-objects).

Answer (score 0):

Strings are compared with the `.equals()` method:

```
input.equals(fileWord)
```

For lines with multiple words, use the [`split()` method](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) to break them apart into an array, then compare `input` against each array element. (And break out of the loop if there's a match).

Answer (score 0):

Do not use == with Strings. Use String.equals.

== compares the id of the objects; not the contents.